# How to solve this ODE's?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I have here this problem, where I want to determine the general solution:

$$ u'= - \frac{2v}{t^2}+ te^t $$
$$ v'=-u+t $$
$ t \in \mathbb{R}^+ $

My idea is here to use variation of parameters, but how do I do this with the system?
Any help very appreciated!

Comment: Show us what steps block you : where do you think you don't know how to proceed ? Applying the general method step by step should be sufficient, perhaps provide some background work ?

Comment: Variation of parameters is a way to get a solution to an inhomogenous linear ODE whose homogeneous solution you already have. Here it's not immediately obvious how to solve $u'=-2v/t^2,v'=-u$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$v'=-u+t$$
Differentiate:
$$v''=-u'+1$$
Substitute this in the first DE:
$$u'= - \frac{2v}{t^2}+ te^t$$
$$-v''+1=- \frac{2v}{t^2}+ te^t$$
$$-t^2v''+{2v}=t^3e^t-t^2$$
This is [Cauchy-Euler 's differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation).